# How to pass GET data and POST data via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, get

I have a small form I'd like to validate with AJAX. (I'm using jQuery)

I'd like to pass the data entered in the inputs by the user (POST method) and some other data that is typically available in my controller/view.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Show what you have done so far, if you are doing a POST might as well POST all of the data so the script handles everything at once.

Comment: Send it all via POST.  What reason do you have to send via POST and GET both?

Comment: none you're right. But how can I send additional info via POST ? Hidden fields ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GET data goes in the URL

```
 /controller/action?name=will&last_name=smith
```

POST data travels in the request body, in several ways form-data, xml, json, etc

Maybe you should try to POST the first url with your request body data

Comment: This answers the question directly as asked, but it might be good to show / suggest a method to pass it all via POST, rather than mix-and-matching.  Should be easy enough to do it all via POST....

Answer (score 1):

just include GET-data into the URL, e.g. 
    http://www.example.com?param=value

and use POST for the rest

Answer (score 0):

you can include the data you want to send in a hidden form field, on the controller process the post request, then redirect to  get